# After deleting a line of data in a file, I tried to print out all the data in the current file,but it printed out the data in pre-deleted file instead

Tags: c

So I wrote a delete function to delete one selected line of data at a time and a view function to print the data in the file. But after deleting a line in the file and using the view function right after, it prints the data of the pre-deleted file instead of the data in the new file.

The delete function:

```
void delete() {
    char name[50];
    printf("Enter the name of the contact you want to delete: ");
    scanf("%s", name);

    FILE *temp_file = fopen("tempfile.txt", "w");
    if (temp_file == NULL) {
        printf("ERROR: Unable to create temporary file.");
        return;
    }

    file1 = fopen("SavedContacts.txt", "r");
    if (file1 == NULL) {
        printf("ERROR: Unable to open file.");
        fclose(temp_file);
        return;
    }

    int deleted = 0;
    char line[100];
    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file1)) {
        char *token;
        strcpy(token, line);
        strtok(token, ":");
        if (strcmp(token, name) == 0) {
            deleted = 1;
            continue;
        } else {
            fputs(line, temp_file);
        }    
    } 

    fclose(file1);
    fclose(temp_file);

    if (deleted) {
        remove("SavedContacts.txt");
        rename("tempfile.txt", "SavedContacts.txt");
        printf("Contact deleted successfully.\n");
        count--;
    } else {
        remove("tempfile.txt");
        printf("Contact not found.\n");
    }
}
```

The view function:

```
void view() {
    file1 = fopen("SavedContacts.txt", "r");
    printf("\t\t Contacts: \n \n");
    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        printf("%s: %s, %s\n", contact[i].name, contact[i].pn, contact[i].email);
    }
    fclose(file1);
}
```

So for example, if there is

```
Test0: 0000, Test0@gmail.com
Test1: 1111, Test1@gmail.com
Test2: 2222, Test2@gmail.com
Test3: 3333, Test3@gmail.com
```

and I deleted the line for Test2
using the view function gave me the output of

```
Test0: 0000, Test0@gmail.com
Test1: 1111, Test1@gmail.com
Test2: 2222, Test2@gmail.com
```

when the data in the file 'SavedContacts' is

```
Test0: 0000, Test0@gmail.com
Test1: 1111, Test1@gmail.com
Test3: 3333, Test3@gmail.com
```

I believe there's something wrong with the view function but I don't know where the problem is

Comment: Welcome to SO. How do the complete functions look like, how do you call them? Please edit your question to include a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also, what is the file content if you check in an text editor? And what is the input you provide to your program?

Comment: How is the file content related to your output at all in your "view" function? You don't read anything from the file. You actually never put anything into `contact` in the code you show. And how is `count` related to the file content? You only decrement after deleting a line but you never increment it. You probably should remove it completely from the program.

Comment: the `count` variable is to count how many contacts there are in the file, there's still an add function to increment the variable

Comment: You do not keep your array consistent to the file content. You should only rely on data from the file and not mix with your array.

Comment: If you didn't understand what Gerhardh was saying, your view() function is showing the contents of the array, not the contents of the file. Even though you open and close the file, but you are not using it. Maybe you meant to do something like this: void view() {
    FILE *file1 = fopen("SavedContacts.txt", "r");
    printf("\t\t Contacts: \n \n");
    char line[100];
    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file1)) {
        printf("%s", line);
    }
    fclose(file1);
}

Comment: Aside: `strcpy(token, line);` is not good. `token` is an uninitialized pointer.

Answer (score 0):

1. `delete()` operates on your file but `view()` on an array `contact` that you haven't told you about.  Either change `delete()` to update the `contact` array (and write array to file possible elsewhere), or change `view()` to operate on the file instead of the array like I did here:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define PATH "SavedContacts.txt"
#define NAME_LEN 49
#define LINE_LEN 99
#define str(s) str2(s)
#define str2(s) #s

FILE *delete(FILE *contacts) {
    char name[NAME_LEN+1];
    printf("Enter the name of the contact you want to delete: ");
    scanf("%" str(NAME_LEN) "s", name);

    FILE *temp_file = fopen("tempfile.txt", "w");
    if (!temp_file) {
        printf("ERROR: Unable to create temporary file.");
        return NULL;
    }

    int deleted = 0;
    char line[LINE_LEN+1];
    while (fgets(line, LINE_LEN+1, contacts)) {
        char *token = strdup(line);
        strtok(token, ":");
        if (strcmp(token, name)) {
            fputs(line, temp_file);
        } else
            deleted = 1;
    }
    fclose(temp_file);
    if (!deleted) {
        remove("tempfile.txt");
        printf("Contact not found.\n");
        return contacts;
    }
    rename("tempfile.txt", PATH);
    printf("Contact deleted successfully.\n");
    return freopen(PATH, "r", contacts);
}

void view(FILE *contacts) {
    printf("\t\t Contacts: \n\n");
    char line[LINE_LEN+1];
    while (fgets(line, LINE_LEN+1, contacts)) {
        fputs(line, stdout);
    }
}

int main(void) {
    FILE *contacts = fopen(PATH, "r");
    if(!contacts) {
        perror(PATH);
        return 1;
    }
    FILE *contacts2 = delete(contacts);
    if(!contacts2) {
        return 1;
    }
    contacts = contacts2;
    view(contacts);
    fclose(contacts);
}
```

and here is the corresponding output:

```
Enter the name of the contact you want to delete: Test0
Contact deleted successfully.
                 Contacts: 

Test1: 1111, Test1@gmail.com
Test2: 2222, Test2@gmail.com
Test3: 3333, Test3@gmail.com
```

2. `strcpy(token, line);` will probably segfault as `token` is not allocated.
3. `count--` refers to (global) a variable that you haven't told us about.
4. Refactored your code to pass in a file handle, this makes your functions easier to test, if you ever want to write some unit tests.
5. Used symbolic contacts instead of magic values.
6. Always use a maximum field width when reading strings with `scanf()` to avoid buffer overflows.

Comment: If that answered your question please accept it by clicking on the next mark next to the answer.